# SQL Report Builder - Multiple Parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, reportbuilder3.0

I have searched and tried so many different things and to me the problem seems to be straight forward.

I have a DataSet that the user can refine by selecting a dropdown of Yes or No - this looks up the database table and pulls out any records where the column value is Yes, the problem is when I look for No - I need this to return all values in the database so where the value is Yes or No.

Can someone please advise?

```
SELECT * FROM @TestTable Where Show=@Show
```

I have set up my Parameter and the Avaliable Values are

```
Yes - with a value of YES
ALL - with a value of IS NOT NULL - this ends up showing nothing
```

EDIT -

TestTable has 2 Columns
    Name | Show

Values are:

```
Name 1 | Yes
Name 2 | Yes
Name 3 | No
Name 4 | Yes
```

My report has the Parameter @Show whwen the report loads they are to choose to display Permanent staff only - if they select Yes then it would pull out

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 4
```

If they select No i need the report to show

```
Name 1 
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Show us some example data and expected output.

Comment: Have added some sample data - hope this helps

Comment: Are you looking to change the query?

Comment: I need the Report Parameter to pass IS NOT NULL to the query, but I think the way it is doing it from Report Builder is SELECT * FROM @TestTable Where Show='IS NOT NULL'

Comment: Yes, that is probably what it is doing. So if you had the query to be `SELECT * FROM @TestTable Where (Show=@Show and @Show='Yes') OR (@Show<>'Yes')` would that not work?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to add some more info on your problem.
But you could use an If statement in your sql or in your server scripting.

MsSql : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

MySql : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html

You could also do something like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE @parameter IS NULL OR Show = @parameter;
```